# Can't make unicode string literal with xor symbol in Python?

Tags: python, unicode, string-literals, unicode-literals

I'm trying to print the xor symbol in Python ().

I can print a universal quantifier just fine:

```
>>> print u"\u2200"
∀
```

But when I do xor, it prints 8 instead:

```
>>> print u"\u10308"
8
```

Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you specify a unicode with `u'\uXXXX'`, the XXXX must be exactly 4 hex digits. To specify a unicode with 8 hexdigits, you must use a capital U: `u'\UXXXXXXXX'`.

So `u'\u10308'` is actually two characters, `u'\u1030'` followed by `u'8'`.

`u'\u1030'` is the [`MYANMAR VOWEL SIGN UU` character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1030/index.htm), which is a non-spacing mark. This character is [not visible along the baseline](http://www.unicode.org/glossary/#nonspacing_mark) in and of itself. So all you end up seeing is the `8`.

---

The symbol you posted is the `OLD ITALIC LETTER THE` unicode character.

```
In [103]: print(u'\N{OLD ITALIC LETTER THE}')


In [104]: print(u'\U00010308')
```

The `XOR` unicode character is:

```
In [105]: print(u'\N{XOR}')
⊻

In [106]: print(u'\u22bb')
⊻
```

Other characters you might find useful:

```
In [110]: print(u'\N{CIRCLED PLUS}')
⊕

In [111]: print(u'\N{CIRCLED TIMES}')
⊗

In [112]: print(u'\N{N-ARY CIRCLED PLUS OPERATOR}')
⨁

In [113]: print(u'\N{N-ARY CIRCLED TIMES OPERATOR}')
⨂
```

---

PS. You can find the Unicode name of (some) unicode characters this way:

```
In [95]: import unicodedata as UD

In [96]: UD.name(''.decode('utf-8'))
Out[96]: 'OLD ITALIC LETTER THE'
```

Answer (score 1):

The primary problem is that the `\u` escape sequence only makes use of the next four hexadecimal digits, so `u"\u10308"` is the string containing Unicode codepoint U+1030 (MYANMAR VOWEL SIGN UU) followed by `8`.  Apparently, your terminal does not have the proper fonts to display Myanmar characters, so the first character does not appear when printed.  In order to specify a Unicode codepoint with more than four hex digits, you need to use `\U` followed by eight digits, i.e., `u"\U00010308"`.  However, note that the character you're trying to obtain is actually OLD ITALIC LETTER THE, which may look like (one of the many symbols for) XOR but is different.  A more appropriate choice for your desired glyph is U+2297 (CIRCLED TIMES, or ⊗).